# How to test if google app engine web application will work in China?

Tags: google-app-engine

So I'm not located in China but want to test my google app engine site in China.  What can I do to test this beside asking someone to do it for me?

Comment: using a web proxy perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/ before, and it seems to work well.

Your app will probably not be accessible from China. I get around this by using nginx as a reverse proxy on Amazon EC2. That way I have my own dedicated IP address that isn't affected by other applications.

http://blog.magicalhobo.com/2011/04/11/running-a-reverse-proxy-for-app-engine-on-amazon-ec2/